# Office 365 .exe equivalent?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, microsoft-onenote

In Office 365, is there an equivalent of the .exe files used by office?

Here's why:

My company just migrated me to Office 365. Unfortunately this breaks some automation that I used prior to the switch: for example I have used an automation tool (ActiveWords) to launch a script every morning that includes opening OneNote and Outlook for use immediately.

The Active Word used OneNote.exe and Outlook.exe to do this, but with Office 365 I have not been able to find anything equivalent I can point to so it can launch these programs.  All of the online tutorials point me to the Windows menu, which abstracts the launch feature, and which cannot be pointed to as a program file, so I don't know how to launch them from ActiveWords.

Does anyone here on SuperUser know how to solve this issue?

It doesn't quite feel like a Super User question, but it feels even less like a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Easiest solution is to run Outlooko and OneNote and then open Task Manager -> find the applications and open their locations. Office365 uses application streaming so it's not a normal installation under "Program Files". It'll inevitably have been streamed under your profile so it'll be a virtual directory somewhere.

Comment: If you have Office 365, then you should have a local installation of Office installed on the system, which uses the same executable names as any version specific edition of Office (i.e. Office 2013, Office 2016, Office 2019).  I am extremely confused by your question for this reason.

Comment: I found an office instance at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16 and using the Task Manager trick that @Kinnectus recommended confirmed that this is the location for the Office 365 applications.  For some reason they will launch the application if I double click them, but they will not launch the application from ActiveWords. So still dead in the water and trying to figure out why that would be.